# How to change font size of headdings without impacting TOC

Tags: fontsize

I am a relatively new to LaTex and I am using a template provided by my university to write my thesis.  The current headings for my chapters are in very large font and when I adjust them using the \Huge, the table of contents entry becomes .8830ptIntroduction with introduction being very small font.  I can't find anywhere in the .tex where the font size is listed.  I know I need to paste the code here but I am not sure what would be useful so I pasted the .tex file.

Thank you for any help.

```
\documentclass[oneside,final, letter]{ucr}

\usepackage{anysize}
\usepackage[left=1.5in,top=1.5in,right=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
% \usepackage{bm}
% \usepackage{mathrsfs}
% \usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
% \usepackage{graphics}
% \usepackage{subfigure}
% \usepackage{flafter}
% \usepackage{sw20uctd}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfsync}
\usepackage{amsmath}
% \usepackage{amssymb}
% \usepackage{amsthm}
% \usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage{fncylab}
\usepackage[usenames]{color}
% \usepackage{enumerate}
% \usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{acknowledgement}[theorem]{Acknowledgement}
\newtheorem{algorithm}[theorem]{Algorithm}
\newtheorem{axiom}[theorem]{Axiom}
\newtheorem{case}[theorem]{Case}
\newtheorem{claim}[theorem]{Claim}
\newtheorem{conclusion}[theorem]{Conclusion}
\newtheorem{condition}[theorem]{Condition}
\newtheorem{conjecture}[theorem]{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{criterion}[theorem]{Criterion}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{exercise}[theorem]{Exercise}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{notation}[theorem]{Notation}
\newtheorem{problem}[theorem]{Problem}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\newtheorem{solution}[theorem]{Solution}
\newtheorem{summary}[theorem]{Summary}
\newtheorem{observation}[theorem]{Observation}
\newenvironment{proof}[1][Proof]{\textbf{#1.} }{\ \rule{0.5em}{0.5em}}
\def\dsp{\def\baselinestretch{2.0}\large\normalsize}
\dsp

%TCIDATA{OutputFilter=LATEX.DLL}
%TCIDATA{Created=Saturday, April 29, 2006 22:07:22}
%TCIDATA{LastRevised=Tuesday, July 17, 2007 22:48:56}
%TCIDATA{<META NAME="GraphicsSave" CONTENT="32">}
%TCIDATA{<META NAME="DocumentShell" CONTENT="Other Documents\SW\Thesis - University of California Thesis">}
%TCIDATA{Language=American English}
%TCIDATA{CSTFile=ucr.cst}


%% tcilatex is a package from Scientific Workplace.
%% The user may remove the following line without serious damage.
%% \input{tcilatex}



\begin{document}

% Declarations for Front Matter

\title{}
\author{}
\degreemonth{December}
\degreeyear{2015}
\degree{Doctor of Philosophy}
\chair{}
\othermembers{}
\numberofmembers{3}
\field{Environmental Toxicology}
\campus{}

\maketitle
\copyrightpage{}
\approvalpage{}

\degreesemester{Spring}

\begin{frontmatter}

\begin{acknowledgements}
\end{acknowledgements}

\begin{dedication}
\null\vfil
{\large
\begin{center}
\end{center}}
\vfil\null
\end{dedication}

\input{abstract}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\end{frontmatter}

% \part{First Part}


\input{chapter1} %usually intro
\input{chapter2}
\input{chapter3}
\input{chapter4}
\input{chapter5}
\input{conclusions}



\nocite{*}
% \singlespacing
% \bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bibfile}

\input{appendix}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you try and reduce the example to a minimal one showing the issue?

Comment: I figured out how to fix the problem using                                                                                                                                                                                                     \usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\setlength\cftbeforechapskip{0pt}
\renewcommand\cftfigafterpnum{\vskip10pt\par}
\renewcommand\cfttabafterpnum{\vskip10pt\par}